# Create dyanmic react sidebar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, sidebar, confluence

I am currently working on a sidebar of a project, where the sidebar should be quite similar to tools like Confluence.

That means we should be able to shift around documents and create subdirectory structure just by shifting the documents and this should be immediately reflected by the frontend. Also changing the names of the title of the document should have immediate impact on the display in the sidebar.

Is there some template for it or some documentation/tutorial to get such a thing done?

Comment: You need a state management solution

Comment: If you use react-states, It will immediately update the title of the document and subdirectories or anything. You will also need to use some state management  solutions like redux or react-contextApi

Comment: @Sagar Many thanks for your input. Could you explain a little further, how we could make use of states here for getting the requirements from above incorporated?

Comment: @SatyamSaurabh This sounds very interesting as well. Could you also add some explanation to it?

Answer (score 0):

[image: State management]

In the above diagram you can see your sidebar and document are subscribed to same state (state is like a in-memory temporary database inside your frontend application )

When you want to update the title of the document, you will update the title in the state not the component, so as the component is subscribed to the state, it will update automatically.

Then as the side bar also subscribes to the same state, title in of the document in the sidebar will also updates.

And make the state updates in your state ( your frontend database ) in sync with your backend persistence. that means when frontend title got updated, you will call your backend API to update the document title.

There are couple of libraries / frameworks which will help you to do in more organized way at scale.

**Easy to adapt**

- Hook State
  https://hookstate.js.org/
- React Query
  https://tanstack.com/query/v4

**Highly scalable but more adaption and learning curve ( needs GraphQL )**

- Relay
  https://relay.dev/
- Apollo Client
  https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/

**The Legend**

- Redux  ( It is you like wring SQL, and other libraries are ORM )
  https://redux.js.org/